# о принципе работы into into

Tags: c#, linq

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять, когда именно данные сохраняются в ws ?

```
string[] websites = { "hsNameA.com", "hsNameB.net", "hsNameC.net",
    "hsNameD.com", "hsNameE.org", "hsNameF.org",
    "hsNameG.tv", "hsNameH.net", "hsNameI.tv"
    };

    var webAddrs = from addr in websites
    group addr by addr.Substring(addr.LastIndexOf('.'))
        into ws
        where ws.Count()>2
        select ws;
```

После группирования домена или в каждом шагу ? Не могу понять, какой последовательностью работают алгоритмы когда используются groupby и into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL-подобный синтаксис разворачивается в последовательный вызов методов расширений LiNQ. В некоторых случаях такой синтаксис легче читается, чем длинные цепочки вызова методов.

Ваш запрос можно переписать так:

```
var groups = websites.GroupBy(addr => addr.Substring(addr.LastIndexOf('.')));
var webAddrs = groups.Where(ws => ws.Count() > 2);
```

Таким образом видно, что сначала формируются все группы и, только после этого, происходит отбор нужных групп.

Если написать последовательность вызова одной строкой (без промежуточной переменной groups) и посмотреть на результат компиляции в IL-код (например в LINQPad), вы убедитесь, что это одно и тоже.